# Scheduling a task in Java to run every X days or execute once only

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, schedule

Both a stackoverflow and a Java beginner here.

So I'm trying to implement a scheduler into my app. I want a certain process / job to run every X amount of time or to run just once. This time needs to be configurable, so I made a simple Schedule object with fields like `startDate`, `lastExecuted`, an enum for the frequency and getters, and setters.

Now, it is easy to make it execute a task every X days for example - I just used Groovy's [TimeCategory](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) and made a thread which constantly runs and checks if the time between the `lastExecuted` and the current time is more than the time specified in the `frequency enum` of the `Schedule`

**The problem** - How do I deal with months? If I set the frequency to monthly how do I handle the different length of months? One alternative, I guess, would be to have a large switch statement for every month. But that doesn't seem like a very good solution. Is it possible to do this in a more elegant way (*preferably without any additional libraries or deprecated Java methods, like Date's getDay() method and etc.*)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Calendar class, i.e. to schedule something on the 1st of each month:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     now.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
     scheduler.scheduleAt(now); // or whatever you are using to schedule
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Date.getDay is deprecated, if you read the [Javadoc on Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate()) it points you to the replacement method for the deprecation.

In this case, you may want to use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to retrieve date and time information.